# RxJS: chunk and delay on a large observable array

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Trying to turn a really large array of objects into chunks of 100 objects and wait 10 seconds before emitting the next 100 objects.
The dataset is coming from a HTTP request.

Here is what I currently have

```
const { Subject, from, of } = require('rxjs');
const { bufferCount, concatMap, flatMap, mergeAll, delay } = require('rxjs/operators');

from(hugeArray)
    .pipe(
        bufferCount(100),
        concatMap(txn => of(txn).pipe(delay(10000))),
        mergeAll(),
        flatMap(data => from(data))
    )
    .subscribe(txns => console.log(txns));
```

This doesn't seem to be working as the console isn't logging anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that this is what you are looking for? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-erd66u
I changed your code a little bit and removed `mergeAll` and `flatMap(...)`. If you want to split an array into chunks and emit the chunks with the delay, you only need `bufferCount()` and `concatMap()`.

Comment: @codeepic Yeah this works great

Comment: I'll make it an answer then ;-D Glad to hear it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on my comment:

[stackblitz working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-erd66u?devtoolsheight=60)

Code - basically only removed `mergeAll()` and `flatMap(...)` lines from the `pipe`.

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, bufferCount, concatMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

from(generateHugeArray(100)).pipe(
  bufferCount(10),
  concatMap(txn => of(txn).pipe(delay(3000))),
  tap(h => console.log('chunk: ', h))
).subscribe();



// helper function
function generateHugeArray(size) {
  const arr = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr.push(i + (Math.random() + '').substring(2,4));
  }

  return arr;
}
```